# ¿Cómo sumar todos lo números pares de un rango? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Este es mi código:

```
function suma(start, end){
  let sum = 0;
  while(start<end){
    if (start%2==0){
      sum+=start;
    }
  start++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Si hago un `console.log(function(20, 30))`, me tendría que retornar 100 (22+24+26+28) pero en su lugar me retorna 120 (20+24+26+28) porque también cuenta el numero inicial para la suma.

¿Qué podría hacer para que solo tome en cuenta el rango?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con incrementar el valor de `start` en una unidad antes de entrar al ciclo sería suficiente.

```js
function suma(start, end){
  let sum = 0;
  start++; // incrementar el inicio en 1 para no incluirlo en el rango
  while(start < end){
    if (start % 2 == 0){
      sum += start;
    }
   start++;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(suma(20,30))
```

Comment: Gracias amigo me funciono, era tan simple xd.

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de hacerlo es aprovechando las matemáticas.

Sabemos que la suma de los elementos de una [progresión aritmética](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progresi%C3%B3n_aritm%C3%A9tica) se puede calcular con la siguiente fórmula:

> `S = ((a_1 + a_n) / 2 ) * n`

Donde, `a_1` es el primer término de la progresión, `a_n` es el último elemento de la progresión, y `n` es la cantidad de téminos que serán sumados.

Como el rango de valores a sumar es abierto (es decir, no incluye los extremos si estos son pares) entonces basta con calcular `a_1` y `a_n` tales que se encuentren dentro del intervalo. Si el intervalo empieza en un valor par, pues `a_1` será dicho valor sumado 2, pero si es impar entonces será dicho valor sumado 1. Para el caso de `a_n`, si el intervalo finaliza en un número par, entonces `a_n` será dicho valor restado 2, si es impar será dicho valor restado 1.

Para calcular `n` basta con dividir el resultado de `a_n - a_1` entre 2 y sumarle una unidad. Esto nos dará la cantidad de elementos pares existentes entre `a_1` y `a_n`.

Con esto, ya tenemos la forma de calcular la suma de todos los números pares en un rango abierto dado.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function sumaPares(inicio, fin) {
  const a_1 = inicio % 2 === 0 ? inicio + 2 : inicio + 1;
  const a_n = fin % 2 === 0 ? fin -2 : fin - 1;
  const n = ((a_n - a_1)/2) + 1;
  return ((a_1 + a_n)/2) * n;
}

console.log(`La suma de pares en el intervalo (20, 30) es: ${sumaPares(20, 30)}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

La ventaja de hacerlo así, es que no hay que realizar un bucle para iterar y sumar, así el cálculo es mucho más rápido para un intervalo muy grande.

Podemos ver un ejemplo de la diferencia de tiempo que hay entre el método iterativo y el método directo:

```js
function sumaPares(inicio, fin) {
  const a_1 = inicio % 2 === 0 ? inicio + 2 : inicio + 1;
  const a_n = fin % 2 === 0 ? fin -2 : fin - 1;
  const n = ((a_n - a_1)/2) + 1;
  return ((a_1 + a_n)/2) * n;
}

function sumaParesIterativo(start, end){
  let sum = 0;
  start++; // incrementar el inicio en 1 para no incluirlo en el rango
  while(start < end){
    if (start % 2 == 0){
      sum += start;
    }
   start++;
  }
  return sum;
}

const inicio = 1;
const fin = 30000000;

console.time('directo');
console.log(`Suma directa: ${sumaPares(inicio, fin)}`);
console.timeEnd('directo');

console.time('iterativo');
console.log(`Suma iterativa: ${sumaParesIterativo(inicio, fin)}`);
console.timeEnd('iterativo');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

**Nota**

La función iterativa fue tomada de la [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547131/c%c3%b3mo-sumar-todos-lo-n%c3%bameros-pares-de-un-rango-javascript/547141#547141).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías simplemente restar el valor inicial `let sum = -start;` , entonces obtienes los demás pares del rango hasta la condición while. Saludos

```
function suma(start, end){
  let sum = -start;
  while(start<end){
    if (start%2===0){
      sum+=start;
    }
  start++;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(suma(10,20));
```

Comment: Podría ser pero imagina que quiero sumar los pares entre 21 y 31 (22+24+26+28+30), tendría que devolver 130 pero en su lugar devuelve 109 porque resta el valor inicial. Por lo que no serviría si el valor inicial es impar.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera se pueden sumar los números intermedios:

```js
function sumEvens(start, end) {
  inicio = start % 2 == 0 ? start + 2 : start + 1;
  final = end % 2 == 0 ? end - 2 : end - 1;

  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = inicio; i <= final; i += 2) {
    console.log(i);
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumEvens(21, 29));
```

Comment: Hola Jhojan, por favor considera agregar una explicación a tu respuesta, explicando cómo resuelve el problema expuesto en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola Jhojan, te sugiero editar tu respuesta, ya que no resuelve el problema planteado, por otro lado te invito a mirar [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!